# Error al intentar abrir tabla de Adventureworks

Tags: mysql, tablas, azure, data, adventureworks

Estoy tomando un curso de análisis de datos y estoy aprendiendo a utilizar SQL en MAC. Estoy usando Azure Data Studio con Docker y para comenzar con las prácticas del curso me pidieron usar la base de datos de Adventureworks 2019 (intenté usar la de 2022 pero Azure no me lo permitió porque no era compatible). Al intentar abrir una de las tablas me arrojó el siguiente mensaje:

> Msg 10347, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Employee, Line 1 Common
> Language Runtime(CLR) is not enabled on this instance. Msg 474, Level
> 16, State 0, Line 1 Unable to load the computed column definitions for
> table "AdventureWorks2019.HumanResources.Employee".

Intenté abrir la tabla usando:

```
select * 
from humanresources.employee
```

Busqué tutoriales relacionados al mensaje que me arroja pero no encontré nada, por lo que agradezco la ayuda que pueda recibir.
Abrí otras tablas sin problema.

Gracias!